# XPath/XQuery - matching all elements containing a particular value

Tags: xpath, xquery

My XML looks a bit like this:

```
<root>
  <child1>
    <grandchild1>{tagID1}<grandchild1/>
    <grandchild2>{tag2}<grandchild2/>
  </child1>
  <child2>{newtag1}<child2/>
<root/>
```

I am looking to retrieve all elements whose text() is like "{*}" i.e. contains a string between 2 curlies, but am not too familiar with xpath.

I thought the xquery syntax would be something like

```
"//*[matches(., '{*}')]"
```

but that is failing with unknown method "-->matches(.<--"

I'd be grateful if someone could correct me please.

Answer (score 4):

The [`matches()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-matches) function is available to XPath 2.0, but your XPath engine probably only supports XPath 1.0.

If that is the case, you'll have to end up with something like this:

```
//*[./text()[starts-with(., '{') and substring(., string-length(.), 1)='}']]
```

It looks for

```
ANY ELEMENT
//*
   THAT HAS A TEXT NODE
   [./text()                                                               ]
            WHICH STARTS WITH A '{'
            [starts-with(., '{')                                          ]
                                 AND ENDS WITH A '}'
                                 and substring(., string-length(.), 1)='}'
```

The `substring()` function call does what you would expect of an `ends-with()` function if there was any in XPath 1.0.

---

**EDIT** (to address OP's comment about `starts-with()` not being found, either)

I haven't ever seen an XPath engine that doesn't know `starts-with()`. If it at least recognizes the `substring()` function, you can try the following workaround:

```
//*[./text()[substring(., 1, 1)='{' and substring(., string-length(.), 1)='}']]
```

which should do the same.

Comment: many thx. Unfortunately it doesn't seem to recognise the "starts-with" function either so I wonder if there is something else going on. I am having to use an old microsoft xml component

Comment: @SimonWoods What. The [`starts-with()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-starts-with) function is valid XPath 1.0. I'll add a `substring()` workaround in just a minute.

Comment: the error reported is 
"Unknown method 
//*[./text()[-->starts-with (.<--, '{') and substring(., string-length(.), 1)='}']]"

Comment: thx again ... but it must be something else then because ...
Unknown method.
//*[./text()[-->substring(.<--, 1, 1)='{' and substring(., string-length(.), 1)='}']]

Comment: @SimonWoods I have no idea what kind of XPath engine that is, but with no function, there's no solution, I fear. Just to be sure: What is the output if you query for example for `//child1`? Does it return the right node? Can you query by attribute values? Do you know any functions that can be passed into it?

Comment: Yes ... it seems to work ok! Wrt other functions which may work - I'll need to have a play. Thx again though

Comment: @SimonWoods I'm sorry, but I'm done here. XQuery should be a superset of XPath 2.0, so BeniBela's solution should work for you. My XPath 1.0 solution should even work for everyone. Try to crawl the documentation of your xml component to see how to access any functions, you might have just missed something trivial. Other than that ... good luck!

Comment: Got it. There was a property "SelectionLanguage" I needed to set to the value "XPath" on the document to enable these xpath queries. (The starts-with then started working not not the matches). Many thx again for your time

Answer (score 3):

Your XPath looks correct, but the xml and regex are wrong.

The {} are special chars and have to be escaped with \. And a * can not be used alone. So the correct expression is (using text() instead of ., so it does not check the text of all descendants) :

```
//*[matches(text(), '\{.*\}')]
```

Although that function is only available in XPath 2 (and XQuery, since it is a superset), you could try the full name `fn:matches`.

In the xml the closing slashes have to be on the other side:

```
<root>
  <child1>
    <grandchild1>{tagID1}</grandchild1>
    <grandchild2>{tag2}</grandchild2>
  </child1>
  <child2>{newtag1}</child2>
</root>
```

Comment: many thx. As per the suggestion from Slanec, I am getting an error ... Unknown method    //*[-->fn:matches(text<--(), '\{.*\}')]